# Speed up Android SDK Emulator

Tags: android-emulator, android-sdk, genymotion

I recently installed Android SDK (not Android Studio or Eclipse) to emulate an Android Watch. I downloaded the ARM images and the Android Support Library. Everything goes fine, except that it is ridiculously slow. It takes five minutes for the emulator to open up and it stays on the boot animation for about the time it takes for me to have a decent dinner with my family. I've upped the RAM to the point where it takes up about 70% of my laptop's RAM and enabled the `Use Host GPU` option. I heard that Genymotion is much faster, but there's no Android Watch or Android TV options in Genymotion. I can't use x86 Images because Intel HAXM requires an Intel processor. Is there anyway to speed up the emulator? Or can I somehow get Android Watch and Android TV in Genymotion Freemium?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the official Android emulator is slow for pretty much everyone. There are numerous Stack Overflow questions about this, including the ones [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/why-is-the-android-emulator-so-slow-how-can-we-speed-up-the-android-emulator), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662650/making-the-android-emulator-run-faster) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399071/why-is-the-android-emulator-slow). Sorry I couldn't be of more help! Using snapshots may help this issue...

Comment: @LJD200 I am aware of that,  but can I instead emulate Watch or TV on Genymotion?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I don't believe that Genymotion supports custom images and these devices aren't supported out-of-the-box.

Comment: That's what I thought. *Sigh*